# Avoid repeated instantiation of InputSource with XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

Currently I am parsing XML messages with XPath Expression. It works very well. However I have the following problem:

I am parsing the whole data of the XML, thus I instantiate for every call made to `xPath.evaulate` a new `InputSource`.

```
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource source = new InputSource(xmlReader);
XPathExpression xpe = xpath.compile("msg/element/@attribute");
String attribute = (String) xpe.evaluate(source, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Now I would like to go deeper into my XML message and evaluate more information. For this I found myself in the need to instantiate source another time. Is this required? If I don't do it, I get Stream closed Exceptions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Parse the XML to a DOM and keep a reference to the node(s). Example:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
    .newXPath();
InputSource xml = new InputSource(new StringReader("<xml foo='bar' />"));
Node root = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/", xml, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("/xml/@foo", root));
```

This avoids parsing the string more than once.

If you must reuse the `InputSource` for a different XML string, you can probably use the [setters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) with a different reader instance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "This avoids parsing the string more than once." ? I did not understand, also your solution does not use XPathExpression classes. Also, could you please help me answering the below post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758074/extract-multiple-xpaths-using-single-inputsource-from-xpathexpression